# can i mix arborio and carnaroli

Tags: risotto

I have 2 lbs of carnaroli rice and 1 lb of arborio rice, both the same brand. I need to make a recipe calling for 3 lbs total. The basic recipe on both boxes call for the same amount of liquid, but I've heard that some people use 1/2 the liquid for carnaroli rice.

I'm wondering if I mix them, will it turn out fine? Is there some adjustment I should make? Just keep stirring and adding liquid until I like the consistency?

Comment: I don't know about those two varieties specifically; I've mixed other types of rice (including mixing a medium and long grain), and it's come out fine ... I just had to sample it and stop the cooking when it reached the point that I liked.

Comment: IMO, everything will be ok; if you have concern about it, just make 2 batches with the 2 different rices.

Comment: I have never heard of using half the liquid for carnaroli. I have used the same risotto recipe with both types of rice with very similar results in terms of consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both arborio and carnaroli are used to make risotto.

If you are making risotto the proper way with adding in your stock over time you will be able to control how much liquid overall goes into the rice and therefore be able to adjust your overall liquid amount as time progresses. Carnaroli has a higher starch content than arborio, but if you mix them together and make risotto I am sure it will turn out just fine and no body will notice. Yes they are different grains, but not enough difference to change things.

[About Carnaroli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnaroli)

[Older discussion re: Carnaroli vs arborio](http://forums.winespectator.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5086097161/m/975104553)